# JQuery Navigation - How to just show one element rather than all of them

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following menu structure (3 Levels)

```
<nav>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" href="">
            Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown 1</a></li>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="display:none">
                <li><a href="#">Sub sub 1</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Sub sub 2</a></li>
            </ul>
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown 2</a></li>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="display:none">
                <li><a href="#">Sub sub 3</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Sub sub 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

Basically, what I want to do is when I mouseover "Dropdown 1" I only see the sub menu that is related to this.. I.e. (sub sub 1, sub sub 2). When I click on "Drop down 2" I get (sub sub 3) and (sub sub 4).

I have tried:

```
var subMenu = $(this).parent().find('ul');
subMenu.show();
```

This is the sub menu, but it is showing all of the sub menus that exist and not just the one that I have hovered over.

What can I do therefore to just limit so that only the sub menu that is being hovered over shows?

Comment: FYI your HTML is invalid - you cannot have `ul` as a direct child of a `ul`, only `li`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

li and ul element cannot have sibling relationship. wrap the inner ul elements in li tag.

and the use `.next()` selector as clicked element li has required li element as next sibling:

**Markup:**

```
<nav>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" href="">
        Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Dropdown 1</a></li>
        <li style="display:none">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
            <li><a href="#">Sub sub 1</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Sub sub 2</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Dropdown 2</a></li>
         <li style="display:none">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Sub sub 3</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Sub sub 4</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

**Script:**

```
var subMenu = $(this).next();
subMenu.show();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nqfq2g4f/)**

Comment: It works, but, for clicking. I need it to work for .hover -- I've tried but with no succsess